# How to Start MapReduce programs?

Tags: mapreduce

I have installed single node cluster in my system(VM->Ubuntu).
I have studies basics of MapReduce and Hadoop Framework. How to get started with MapReduce Coding?

Comment: Start here perhaps? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0

Answer (score 0):

To understand MR please start with Why Big Data is needed and how the traditional problems of JOIN which was solved with SQL needs a different perspective as data is growing huge.

Please follow these amazing links which helped me .

1. http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/understanding-map-reduce-the-missing-guide/
2. http://bytepadding.com/map-reduce/

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have installed Hadoop. Create a new user in ubuntu  $ sudo adduser hduser sudo. change user to 'hduser'(id used while Hadoop configuration,you can switch to the userid used during your Hadoop programming config. Install Java, Install ssh, Extract Hadoop into /home/hduser. Set JAVA HOME, HADOOP HOME , PATH environment variables in to .bashrc file. Create a new directory, write the program and compile the java files and make sure that you give all permissions to the files.it is there in local filesystem only we have to copy into HDFS. Output directory will be there HDFS, to check output